# A question on $K^\text{nor}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have this question

> Let $a$ be a number which is not a power of $p$, consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(a^{1/p})$. I want to show that $K^\text{nor}=K(\xi_p)$ and $[K^\text{nor}:K] = p-1$.

The problem is that in each book I am using there's no mention of $K^\text{nor}$, not Stewart, not another book.

I am clueless here.

Any advice?

Comment: What do you denote $\xi_p$ here?

Comment: I believe it's meant $\xi_p= \exp{2i\pi/p}$.

Comment: But this is a $p$-th root of $1$, not of $a$.

Comment: What do _you_ mean by the notation $K^{\rm nor}$? Since the textbooks you're consulting don't use that notation, you should probably assume it is not familiar to readers here either.

Comment: take for example $x^p-a=0$, then the solution to this problem is $x=a^{1/p}\xi_p^k$ where $k$ is between zero and $p-1$.

Comment: @Troposphere it means the normal closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $x^p-a$ is irreducible
- The splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(a^{1/p},\xi_p)$.
- $[\Bbb{Q}(a^{1/p}):\Bbb{Q}]=p$.
- $[\Bbb{Q}(\xi_p):\Bbb{Q}]=p-1$
- Conclude from the tower law for degree of extensions and that $\mathrm{lcm}(p,p-1)$ divides $[\Bbb{Q}(a^{1/p},\xi_p):\Bbb{Q}]$